# A general iterator to replace "non-standard" C-style for loops

Tags: generics, swift, iterator

Since the [deprecation of C-style for loops](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md) in Swift 2.2 (and the removal in Swift 3),
several questions about the possible replacements [were asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Swift+c+style+for+loop+deprecated). In most cases, a `for .. in` loop
is the appropriate replacement:

```
for i in 1 ... 5 { /* ... */ }
for j in 10.stride(through: 0, by: -2) { /* ... */ }
for elem in array.reverse() { /* ... */ }
```

and similar. However, there are cases where this pattern cannot be used:

- The stride (advance) is not constant.
- The terminating condition is "dynamic" (depends on the loop variable),
  as in [Swift replacement for C's for-loop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118445/swift-replacement-for-cs-for-loop).
- The loop variable is not a strideable type (e.g. a linked list).

In all these cases, the C-style for loop can be replaced by a while or repeat/while statement:

```
var iterationVariable = "initial value"
while "condition" {
    //
    //  do something
    //

    iterationVariable = "compute next value"
}
```

However, this has some disadvantages (and I cannot formulate it better than
@nhgrif did in [Swift replacement for C's for-loop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118445/swift-replacement-for-cs-for-loop)):

> And the biggest problem with the while loop which I'd like reviewed is
>   that the divisor variable has a scope larger than I'd like, and the
>   update statement doesn't come until the very end of the while loop (a
>   problem that becomes more complex if your loop has any continue
>   statements in it anywhere that allow iterations to break out early and
>   jump to the next iteration).

For my own educational purposes, I wrote the following general
iteration functions which can be used as a C-style for loop replacement 
in such cases (requires Swift 2.2/Xcode 7.3):

```
func iterate<T>(from from : T, while condition : T -> Bool, next : T -> T) -> AnySequence<T> {

    var current = from
    let condition = condition
    let next = next

    return AnySequence { 
        return AnyGenerator {
            if !condition(current) {
                return nil
            }
            defer {
                current = next(current)
            }
            return current
        }
    }
}

func iterate<T>(from from : T, until condition : T -> Bool, next : T -> T) -> AnySequence<T> {

    var current = from
    let condition = condition
    let next = next
    var done = false

    return AnySequence {
        return AnyGenerator {
            if done {
                return nil
            } else if condition(current) {
                done = true
                return current
            } else {
                defer {
                    current = next(current)
                }
                return current
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A simple usage example is

```
for i in iterate(from: 1, while: { $0 * $0 < 100 } , next: { 2 * $0 }) {
    print(i, terminator: ", ")
}
// Output: 1, 2, 4, 8,
```

In contrast to the while loop, the scope of the loop variable is exactly the loop body, and the syntax is remotely similar to the C-style for loop. But in contrast to the C-style for loop, the loop variable is a *constant* within the body.

The return value of the `iterate()` functions is a `SequenceType`,
so you can create an array from it directly. The following 
example computes the ["3n+1 sequence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) for a given
integer:

```
func collatz(n : Int) -> Int {
    return n % 2 == 0 ? n / 2 : 3 * n + 1
}

func collatzValues(n : Int) -> [Int]{
    return Array(iterate(from: n, until: { $0 == 1 } , next: collatz))
}

print(collatzValues(13)) // [13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

And finally an example where you iterate over a linked list of
network interfaces
(compare [How to get Ip address in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626117/how-to-get-ip-address-in-swift/25627545#25627545)):

```
var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs> = nil
if getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 {
    for ptr in iterate(from: ifaddr, while: { $0 != nil }, next: { $0.memory.ifa_next }) {
        let addr = ptr.memory.ifa_addr.memory
        // ...
        // Do something with this sockaddr 
        // ...
    }
    freeifaddrs(ifaddr)
}
```

To compile this example,

```
#include <ifaddrs.h>
```

must be added to the bridging header file.

*What I would like* is a review on all aspects of the two `iterate()` functions (the examples
were just added to demonstrate the usage), including but of course
not limited to:

- naming of function, parameters, variables,
- Swifty-ness of the code, possible simplifications,
- possible performance improvements (iterating over the sequences
  created by the `iterate()` functions is much slower than the
  equivalent while loop).

In addition, any thoughts on the usefulness of those functions are
welcome.